# Display text from a stream XHR response chunk by chunk

Tags: javascript, stream

I'm trying to display the streamed text returned from a XHR call, chunk by chunk (wihtout waiting for the response to be complete). Like ChatGPT responses.

```js
    async read(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain",
            },
        });

        const data = response.body;
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        const reader = data.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let done = false;

        while (!done) {
            const {value, done: doneReading} = await reader.read();
            done = doneReading;
            console.log(decoder.decode(value));
        }
    },
```

But for now, the console.log() only display the full text once the request is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine. Maybe your data is smaller than the buffer size.

Your HTTP server should not buffer your output. Sometimes HTTP server buffers all the output and issues it in one chunk.

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seductiveapps/largeJSON/master/100mb.json';
  
  read(url);
  
  async function read(url) {
  
        const {body} = await fetch(url);
        
        const reader = body?.getReader();
        if (!reader) {
            return;
        }

        let value, done, min, max;
        do {
          ({value, done} = await reader.read());
          if (value) {
            min = Math.min(...[min, value.length].filter(Boolean));
            max = Math.max(...[max, value.length].filter(Boolean));
            console.log( value.length );
          }
        } while(!done);
        
        console.log(
          'min buffer size:',
          Math.round(min/1024), 
          'kb, max buffer size:', 
          Math.round(max/1024),
          'kb'
        );
        
        
    };
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work on my case because my URL is a stream, not a static file

Comment: @Sylvain there's no difference, what is size in bytes of your output? probably too small and so it's read in one `reader.read()` call

Comment: @Sylvain your HTTP server should output it in chunks. sometimes HTTP server buffers all the output and issues it in one chunk.

Comment: My server is a Symfony project rendering a StreamedResponse, from a GPT generated text, so it takes ~1min to output fully

Comment: @Sylvain 1 min = generation time, not streaming. make sure you output your data without buffering. still seems your output is buffered. i guess you should ask how not to buffer your symfony output

Comment: Yes I think the issue is on the backend side, I'm investigating. Thanks

Comment: @Sylvain you could at least upvote my answer (the arrow up) for my efforts, thanks

Comment: Hi @AlexanderNenashev I am facing the exactly same issue. Could you please show how to shrink the HTTP server buffers to make showing the streaming result chunk by chunk?  I am using FastAPI with Uvicorn to launch the server. On the website side, I use the VSCode extension Live Server released by Ritwick Dey. I'm not sure the buffer in which side caused this issue. Appreciate if you could help.

Comment: Hi @Sylvain have you found the solution?