# Is fetch read stream data after all chunk received but not read once a chunk received?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, server-sent-events

I am handling stream response which content-type is `text/event-stream` with `fetch`, `reader` and `decoder`, however it seems that the reader returns after all chunk received, this is not as excepted since I thought reader will return when chunk received as soon as possible. Do I handle stream response in a wrong way?

```
const sseController = new AbortController();
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'text/event-stream,application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ...params,
    }),
    signal: sseController.signal,
}).then(async (response) => {
    console.log('sselog::: open', new Date());
    if (!response.ok || !response.body) {
        // TODO onerror
        return;
    }

    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

    while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader?.read();
        console.log('sselog::: while', value);
        const str = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
        // TODO onmessage
        if (done) {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

You can see that `sselog::: while` only output once, but actually backend received two messages which type is `major` and `message`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem isn't your fetch code but in the backend. Your HTTP server shouldn't buffer and must issue data immediately.

Here's the test with chunked fetch:
[Display text from a stream XHR response chunk by chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76515222/display-text-from-a-stream-xhr-response-chunk-by-chunk/76515422#76515422)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works as expected after I set my webpack devserver compression to false. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @smilebuz since my answer helped to resolve the issue you are welcome to accept it with the checkbox and upvote with the arrow up, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure out finally. Set server compression to false.